# Spring Cloud Eureka Netflix zuul filters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I have three spring boot micro services which uses spring Eureka server and zuul as gateway. I have auth micro service which is zuul gateway which validates user. I have two other services which is running in different ports. I am able to protect the two services with the help of jwt, if i call via zuul gateway but since i know two micro services port and url i can able to call and get the response directly without via gateway url . So i how to protect the the two micro services. Please help me to share the security context between two micro services.

Comment: can you share you code what you did yet

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for security settings in each other the microservices that are not zuul or eureka.

With help of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter you could override the CORS settings and only accept requests from a certain service, that way zuul can talk to the services, and maybe even each service to each other. But postman and other clients couldn't do that.

Comment: So it means each service do i need to write class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class. If i do that then i could not make call from zuul gateway service from other micro services. Because it will unauthorised error

Comment: With JWT you need a filter mechanism to extract token data into a SecurityContextHolder. Thus you need the JWTFilter which requires the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to activate. You could externalise the JWT logic in a seperate project and import it per project via the POM to prevent copy pasting code. With OAuth or OpenID you wouldn't need to do this, but with JWT you need to extract it yourself. Although it's only just a single filter that can be copied per service, not too much hassle for security if you ask me.